# Usage of “ in the manner “

Tags: conjunctions

Is it correct to use  “in the manner“ in sentence

> The word “you“ is used in the manner “u“ .

I mean Can “in the manner“ be used as “as“ .

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "in the manner" like that.

You can use "in the manner of" to mean "copying the style of (a particular person or thing)"

> He clapped his hands in the manner of a sumo wrestler.

A sumo wrestler has a particular style of clapping, so you can talk about the "manner of a sumo wrestler".  But "u" doesn't have a particular style. Your sentence doesn't make much sense.

In the particular example you give, I would say

> The word "you" is written "u".